# How to make an clean shadow box in beamer?

Tags: beamer

Here's [an example](http://www.john-crosby.co.uk/pdfs/JCrosby_OxfordJune2013_Levy.pdf):

[image]

This style is clean for lecture notes or some academic use. Anybody knows how to realize such pretty style? I'm really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `fancybox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{\shadowbox{Motivation}}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item bla 
  \item bla 
  \end{itemize} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By the way, here is the way i managed to set it in the template

\usepackage{fancybox}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{2cm}\centering \large \large\shadowbox{ \ \insertframetitle \quad \small p\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \ }\par\vskip-6pt}