# Beamer template recommendation

Tags: beamer

I want to replicate the attached simple template style for a presentation. Is it available in beamer please? I do not want the usual Madrid/Warsaw style.

[image: pic's]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48183/framed-frame-in-beamer to get frame around the content

Comment: And for the frametitle: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311273/how-to-make-an-clean-shadow-box-in-beamer